# Accessing tables from different .mdb files

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, database-design

I need to show a grid of saved projects (compare "orders") in a datagrid, where the projects are saved in an Access 2000 database with a similar schema as follows:

```
ID     Name      Country_ID   Plant_Type
1      'Test'    1            1
2      'Second'  2            2
```

Let's call the file "Projects.mdb". This is then showed in the datagrid as:

```
ID     Name      Country      Plant Type
1      'Test'    'Germany'    'Free Range'
2      'Second'  'France'     'Inclined Roof'
```

where the countries and "Plant Types" are fetched from a different table in a different .mdb file (also Access 2000, call it "Language.mdb", although there is a lot of different background data in it), depending on the current user's language preference. It is unfortunately not an alternative to merge these .mdb's into one file.

To be able to show the datagrid I have so far linked the tables from "Language.mdb" into "Projects.mdb", but this screws up when the project is being installed on another computer with the .msi file i created (we'd like to have this easily packaged and installed), as the "Language.mdb" doesn't exist on the linked path on the target computer (Basically the problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1661788/relative-table-links-in-ms-access)). 
I can come up with the following solutions:

- Force all users to install on the same path, so that the links will work (undesirable)
- Use connection strings in the query as shown [here on MSDN](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/113701) (still trying this out, but I need to work on the details)
- make a post-install script that relinks the tables according to the correct path.

But I think I'm doing something wrong here. As stated above, it is not an option to merge the .mdb-files, but other suggestions to changing the database schema or whatever it could be (I'm not very experienced with databases) would be very appreciated.

Comment: Andrew: yes, I am using a dataset to populate a DataGridView. does that mean I can put this together outside of the query/-ies?

Comment: Have you considered using the IN 'c:\databases\MyDatabase.mdb' clause in your SQL strings? You could then write them at runtime according to the user's particular configuration.

Comment: IN can get quite tedious if the queries are complex. Linked tables are easier.

Comment: Sure, linked tables are easier, if you're using Access. But the vb.net tag indicates to me that he's not.

Comment: David-W-Fenton: Yes, I guess that was stupid. I'm actually using JET to access the database files, which are in MS Access 2000 format.

Answer (score 1):

To get around the 'different install paths' problem I use code (on every database load) which first looks for any back end databases in the current db folder; if not found, it asks the user to locate the missing .mdb file.  Then the code relinks the database(s). Once the dbs have been successfully linked, the database saves the path and checks this path first on subsequent loads.

Comment: I think the vb.net tag indicates that this isn't an Access app.

Answer (score 0):

Well, based on the constraints that you have put on the solution.  I would either go with option 2 or 3.  There is not an elegant solution to this at all.

I would however, lean towards your third option, as a "one time" fix to get the files linked, so that the path between them is known, and you are not dynamically adding path information into every query.

*note*

I'll just mention, but I'm sure you already know this, that if you are looking at doing something like this, it just feels wrong to be doing it with Access, let alone access 2000 at this time for client deployments.  I would strongly recommend additionally truly evaluating the solution and see if you can either merge to one, or possibly move to SQL Server Express or something that you could send off to the user as an installer

Comment: Please explain exactly what aspects of the original question indicate that the project exceeds the capabilities of Jet 4.0 as a data store.

Comment: This type of configuration is easier to manage, deploy and configure if you do not have to rely on physical file paths and other items.  As I noted it is just a general gut feeling that this isn't the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

Is Project split, as it should be, to allow a front end on each user's computer? If so, can you not store the path on the front-end and only re-link if it changes? Code to re-link tables is quite simple, for the most part. The user can be allowed to browse for the location and the Connect property can be updated accordingly.